# .Net mixing unmanaged x32 and x64 dlls

Tags: .net, dll, x86, 64-bit, unmanaged

I have a dependency on an unmanaged dll.
I can compile the unmanaged dll in both x86 and x64.

I want to add my project both the x64 and x86 dlls, so it could dynamically choose between the x64 or x86 dlls depend on the system environment execution.

I know I can have to releases, one as x64 and one as x86, but I would rather it to behave like an AnyCpu single dll.

Edit1:

I don't want to user [DllImport] attribute. I'm searching for a more elegant way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have a dependency on native DLLs you will need to have separate build configurations for each CPU architecture. The AnyCPU target can only be used when you only depend on managed assemblies.